# Find and delete elements from slice in golang

Tags: go, slice

I have slice of numbers like `[1, -13, 9, 6, -21, 125]`. I want to find elements that are less than zero then delete them.

It can be done by straightforward way: 
just iterate through slice and if element less than zero -> delete it. But it computationally costly because of possible slice changing on each step.

Is there any elegant way of doing it like `numpy.where(array, condition)` and `numpy.delete`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Copy the surviving elements to the beginning of the slice, and reslice when done.

```
p := []int{1, -13, 9, 6, -21, 125}
j := 0

for _, n := range p {
    if n >= 0 {
        p[j] = n
        j++
    }
}
p = p[:j]
```

No memory is allocated, but the original slice is modified. If you cannot modify the original slice, then allocate and copy to a new slice:

```
p := []int{1, -13, 9, 6, -21, 125}
j := 0
q := make([]int, len(p))
for _, n := range p {
    if n >= 0 {
        q[j] = n
        j++
    }
}
q = q[:j] // q is copy with numbers >= 0
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/gve4zlEqgaT)